# AutoMapper - flatten domain model to view model. One is to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, automapper

I have a complex domain model which has many relationships with other entities in the system.

For the purpose of editing this model I want to set up a view model that simplifies things. I want to break up the model into smaller logical chunks with edit screens for each part instead of trying to represent the whole model on one screen.

In the domain model where I have a one is to many relationship it is represented like this:

```
public partial class CbItemsContent
{

    public CbItemsContent()
    {
        this.cbItemsContentRegulators = new HashSet<cbItemsContentRegulator>();
    }

    public int ItemContentId { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
   ......

    public virtual CbItem CbItem { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<cbItemsContentRegulator> cbItemsContentRegulators { get; set; }
}
```

cbItemsContentRegulator is another set of entities that are owned by CbItemsContent (the model shown above)

I would like to replace the Collection of cbItemsContentRegulators in my model with a simplified viewModel called ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel like this:

```
public class ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel
{
    public int ItemContentId { get; set; }

    public int[] RegulatorIds { get; set; }
}
```

which reduces the relationship to the ItemContent parent ID and an int array if Regulator IDs

is what I am trying to do possible?

How do I Map My collection of CbItemsContentRegulators to an int[] of Ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Entity Framework, you should change the view model to

```
public class ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel
{
    public int ItemContentId { get; set; }
    public IList<int> RegulatorIds { get; set; } // IList
}
```

No you can define the mapping:

```
var profile = Mapper.CreateProfile("SomeName");
profile.CreateMap<CbItemsContent,ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.RegulatorIds,
          m => m.MapFrom(src => src.cbItemsContentRegulators.Select(c => c.RegulatorId)));
```

Now you can use it in a query like:

```
context.CbItemsContents.ProjectTo<ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel>()
```

With `RegulatorIds` as an array this would throw an exception that `ToArray` is not recognized.